# From Scala to Java 1.8

Tags: java, scala, lambda, bigdata, apache-spark

I would like to write a Spark program that parses a csv log file, splits the words by a separator ";" and creates an object, who's attribute values are words located on specific positions. 
The code would look like this in Scala but I am having trouble in translating this to Java 1.8 (I would like to use the lambda expressions in Java).

```scala
val file = sc.textFile("hdfs:/../vrLogs.csv") 
class VREvent(val eventTimestamp: String, val deviceID: String, val eventType: String, val itemGroupName: String)
val vrEvents = file.map(_.split(';')).filter(_.size == 32).map(a => new VREvent(a(0), a(1), a(6), a(13)))
```

I am not sure how to translate this part to Java: `.map(a => new VREvent(a(0), a(1), a(6), a(13)))`.

I tried this (without the filter part):

```java
JavaRDD<String> records = lines.flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(";"))).map(a -> new CDREvent(a[0], a[1], a[6], a[13]));
```

Comment: please, format your code!

Comment: so, you are asking for `map` method equivalent in Java 1.8, right?

Comment: Sorry for the format, I typed too quickly. I am asking for the equivalent of this: ".map(a => new VREvent(a(0), a(1), a(6), a(13)))" in Java 1.8. Thanks!

Comment: Streams in Java 1.8 have map method, too. What stops you?

Comment: P.S. it's not me who downvoted this question

Comment: Yes, they have but how would you write this lambda expression? a => new VREvent(a(0), a(1), a(6), a(13))

Comment: I already tried that.

Comment: You get individual elements from Lists in Java with `a.get(0)`, not `a[0]`; the latter syntax can only be used with arrays, not Lists.

Comment: Also, what forces you to migrate to Java from Scala?

Comment: Of course, you could also just skip the `Arrays.asList` and pass along a `String[]` instead of a `List<String>`.

Comment: @DavidConrad I tried but:Multiple markers at this line
 - The method get(int) is undefined for the 
  type String
 - The method get(int) is undefined for the 
  type String
 - The method get(int) is undefined for the 
  type String
 - The method get(int) is undefined for the 
  type String

Comment: @DavidConrad CDREvent has only String attributes

Comment: Also, why are you using `flatMap`? You don't want a stream of the individual Strings, you want a stream of either arrays or Lists you can pluck items 0, 1, 6, and 13 from.

Comment: You were getting that error because your `flatMap` was taking all the items from the list produced by `Arrays.asList` and sending them along as separate elements of the stream; thus, in your `map` the type of `a` was `String`, not `List<String>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `lines` is a `Stream<String>`:

```
List<CDREvent> events =
    lines
        .map(s -> s.split(";"))
        .filter(a -> a.length == 32)
        .map(a -> new CDREvent(a[0], a[1], a[6], a[13]))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Map each line to a `String[]`, filter out all arrays that are not of length 32, map each `String[]` to a `CDREvent`, and collect them in a new list.

Comment: Thank you @DavidConrad this solves my problem and helps me understand better the way it works!